# How to Write in a loop into a binary file in C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, binaryfiles

I have the following snippet where I read sent bytes using`read()` and store the data in a buffer which works well. But how do i make it so that I can continue to write in binary file after every read. My assumption is that it might have something to do with not resetting the buffer. Thanks for the help!

```
fp = fopen (filename, "wb"); //create a file

while (size > 0){        
    n = read(socket,buffer,size*sizeof(char));
    if (n <=0)
        return -1;
    p += n;
    size -= n;

    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),size*sizeof(char),fp); //write the content to the file

}
```

Comment: You shall proof `fp` if `fopen()` was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `n` in the call to `fwrite()`, not `size`. `n` is the amount you just read from the socket, `size` is how many more bytes you're still waiting for.

```
fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),n,fp);
```

You also shouldn't multiply by `sizeof` there. The second argument is the size of each element, the third argument is the number of elements; `fwrite()` performs the multiplication internally. It happens to work in your case because `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so the multiplication didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes this was the problem actually! Thank you !